# Is it possible to prevent UIMenuController from being dismissed when one of it's UIMenuItems is selected?

Tags: ios, uikit, uimenucontroller, uimenuitem

The default behaviour is that selecting an item will dismiss the menu. I see that some Apple's apps have items which will do some action but keep the menu open.

For example in Notes, there is Indent item which will indent the text but keep the menu open.

Is it possible to achieve this with the public API?

Comment: This was commonly used to keep the menu showing (inside the menu item selector): `UIMenuController.shared.isMenuVisible = true`. Curiously, `.isMenuVisible` has been deprecated as of `iOS 13.0`, and I haven't found a viable alternative. It still works, but as with all deprecations, may not be reliable.